12 volt resistance sensor to 5 volt
My truck has a 12 volt fuel level sensor that works based on resistance. Full the resistance is 33.5 ohms, empty it is 240 ohms. I'd like to take that signal and step it down to 5 volts for use with an Arduino. It doesn't have to be 100% accurate but I'd like it to be pretty close.
EDIT:
Below is the wiring diagram from the service manual for the current 12v gauge/sensor.
My hope was I could tap into wire 29 PK. From there I would be able to run the tank from empty to full and see what voltages correspond to sensor readings and somehow translate that to the 5v signal needed by my ECM.  The ECM table for the fuel level sensor is also below.  I have the ability to edit values in that table
.  What I'm not sure of how I would "scale" the values from 12 volts to 5.



Do you intend to leave it connected to the existing fuel gauge?

it almost certainly does not produce a full voltage range from 0 to 12V

Yes, I'd like to keep the existing gauge connected. The reason for the 5 volt circuit is I want to mimic the level sensor for my ECM which has 5 volts on the fuel level sensor pin vs 12 from the truck. The reason for the difference is I swapped a different drivetrain into the truck.

Sadly, if the original gauge is still connected, then that's what determines sensor current, and prevents you from setting up your own conditions for resistance measurement. If we knew more about the gauge itself, then perhaps we can help.

@SimonFitch I added more details to the original question.

Most fuel gauges don’t work the way a lot of people might expect. You might think the sensor rheostat is part of a voltage divider and the gauge just measures the voltage, but it’s trickier than that. The gauge has two coils in series, one pulls the needle towards empty, the other pulls it towards full. The empty side one connects to +12 V, the full side one to ground, and the sensor connects to the center. When the fuel is low the resistance is low, which increases the current to the empty coil while shunting current away from the full coil. As the level goes up so does the resistance, reducing current to the empty coil while shunting less away from the full coil. The trick is that because the needle position depends on the relative magnetic fields of two coils rather than the absolute magnetic field of a single coil as in a voltmeter, the voltage supply doesn’t need to be well regulated, making it a better design for a vehicle.
You’d have to take this into account, if you wanted to read the sensor with the gauge still connected you would need to find the range of voltages across the sensor and compensate for changes in battery voltage or regulate the voltage to the gauge, or if you’re replacing the gauge with a the Arduino you’d have to use the sensor in a voltage divider with a regulated voltage feeding it.

I added some more details above.  I'm not sure if my gauge behaves the way you describe or not.  I'm wondering if there's a voltage divider already built that would do this or if I'd have to make one.
